# await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB) continues although taskA and taskB are in infinite loop (both with await in the middle)

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

`await Task.WhenAll(a, b);` continues albeit neither `a` nor `b` have completed (as they're in infinite loop)

```
public partial class App : Application, {
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        var a = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            while (true) {
                Trace.WriteLine("A ->");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
                Trace.WriteLine("-> A");
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        var b = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
            while (true) {
                Trace.WriteLine("B ->");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.09));
                Trace.WriteLine("-> B");
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    
        await Task.WhenAll(a, b);
        // I expected that the following line will never run, but it does:
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Why is that?

## edit:

Apparently the editor/plugin/whatever misguided me here:

[image: Misguiding tooltip]

Comment: I suggest you read [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `await Task.WhenAll(a, b);` continues albeit neither `a` nor `b` have completed

But they *have* completed.  That's exactly why `WhenAll` is completing as well.  You can see this yourself by simply inspecting the status of the tasks at that point in time.

Since you're passing an `async` method to `StartNew`, it's going to return a `Task<Task>`.  The outer task will be completed as soon as it *starts* the inner task.  It will not wait to be completed until the inner task finishes.  While you *could* unwrap the tasks and pass those inner tasks to `WhenAll`, you could just as easily *not wrap the tasks in the first place* as you're not accomplishing anything by doing so.

Just invoke the `async` lambdas yourself to create the tasks that you want.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Func<Task> a = async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("A ->");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
                Trace.WriteLine("-> A");
            }
        };
        Func<Task> b = async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("B ->");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.09));
                Trace.WriteLine("-> B");
            }
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(a(), b());
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it... but how can I use e.g. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` ?

Comment: @Tar You have no reason to.  Rather than creating a new task that will be scheduled to run at a later date using the current synchronization context you can just *run it right now* while you're currently in the current synchronization context.

Comment: This is the answer that I din't write. I'd have preferred to use async methods instead of delegates, though.

Comment: @usr I considered mentioning it, but didn't bother as it's strictly a matter of taste.  It is what I'd have done though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Use `Task.Run` instead.

`Task.Factory.StartNew` pre-dates async-await so it doesn't expect an async delegate (i.e. `Func<Task>`). In that case it returns a `Task<T>` where `T` is itself a `Task`. So `a` and `b` aren't `Task`s, they are `Task<Task>`. `Task.Factory.StartNew` here only starts a task that returns the actual task you want to wait for.

You can use `Unwrap` on `a` and `b` to return a task that represents the entire operation, meaning:

```
await Task.WhenAll(a.Unwrap(), b.Unwrap());
```

But, `Task.Run` is simpler and does that implicitly.

Comment: How can I use e.g. `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` with `Task.Run` ?

Comment: @Tar you can't. In that case use `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Unwrap` the tasks it returns.

Comment: Actually `a` and `b` are `Task`s, I can't `Unwarp` them.. (see my edit: it compiles...)

Comment: @Tar `Task<T>` derives from `Task` so you can store any task in a `Task` variable. But in this case the tasks also have a return value, which is a task so they are `Task<Task>`.

Comment: I think he wants to stay on the UI thread and shouldn't use any of this. I won't take the time to answer that in detail. Just leaving that insight here as a comment.

Comment: What do you mean? `a` is `Task`, not `Task<WhatEver>`, this is what I see in the code, in the debugger, it doesn't return any value, it's an `Action`, not `Func`. It doesn't have an `Unwrap()` method so I can't call it. @usr: ignore the UI issue, how can I use custom `TaskScheduler` in this case?

Comment: Can you update the question use a TaskScheduler like you want? If you want to run all of this on the UI thread, why use tasks at all? You are there already.

Comment: @usr, OK, see my edit: let's say I want them to run in the UI, still I want to wait for all tasks in a simple manner, avoiding complex code like `for (int i=0; i<listOfTasksToWaitFor.Count(); i++) { await listOfTasksToWaitFor[i]; }`, I just can't avoid it?

Comment: @i3arnon, I don't understand how, just cast it?

Comment: @Tar The objects are *actually* `Task<Task>` objects.  You're the one who put them in a `Task` object in the first place, even though that's not their actual type.  You don't need to cast it, you just need to keep it its original type.

Comment: @Tar change your code to `Task<Task> a = ...` and `Task<Task> b = ...` or easier do `var a = ...` and `var b = ...`, then `Unwrap()` will work.

Comment: All that said, rather than unwrapping the task it's way easier to just *not wrap it in the first place* given that you're accomplishing nothing by wrapping the task and then immediately unwrapping it.